# In Rails 3's "rails runner", how do you use number_to_human_size() method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionview

In a `rails console`, it can be done this way:

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > helper.number_to_human_size 1
 => "1 Byte" 
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > helper.number_to_human_size 100000
 => "97.7 KB" 
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > helper.number_to_human_size 0
 => "0 Bytes" 
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > helper.number_to_human_size 100000000
 => "95.4 MB"
```

but what about in a `rails runner`?  Is it running as a Controller?  When I print out `self.class` it merely says `Object`

Answer (score 4):

In your runner script, just add this to the top:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'action_view'
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
```